# For which prime numbers $p$ does $x^3 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod{p}$ have a nontrivial solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

For which prime numbers $p$ does $x^3 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod{p}$ have a nontrivial (i.e. $x$ is not congruent to $-1$) solution? I have tried to factorize $x^3 + 1 = (x^2 - x + 1)(x + 1)$ but I don't know what to do now...

Comment: An eventual non-trivial solution is of (multiplicative) order six, and $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic of order $p-1$ so we need $6\mid p-1$. Are you familiar with those facts about $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ and cyclic groups? We can also try quadratic reciprocity to reach the same conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, there is always the trivial solution $x \equiv -1$, so we won't consider that.

Note that if $x^3+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, then $x$ has multiplicative order 6, so $ p \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$, by Lagrange's theorem.

Also note that in this case, the converse of Lagrange's theorem holds, as $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is cyclic, i.e. for every divisor of $(p-1)$, there is an element of that order in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$.

So suppose that $p \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$, then there is an element $x$ of order $6$, then $x^3$ has order 2, i.e. is a root of the polynomial $t^2-1$. But the only roots of $t^2-1$ are $-1$ and $1$, but $x^3 \neq 1$, for else $x$ would have order $3$. Thus $x^3=-1$, i.e. $x^3+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

Also note that $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \Leftrightarrow p \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$ for primes $p$.